# How can I empty all the results in the database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the `db:seed` task which can add me initial data in the database. Is there anyway of clearing the database, so that it will remove all the contents of all the databases, but leave the tables there, so that I don't have to run all the migrations again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you re-setup a clean database, you shouldn't run the migrations, you should load the `schema.rb` via `db:schema:load` (bigger projects will have code in migrations that won't run anymore, for example because classes were renamed).

```
rake db:drop db:create db:schema:load db:seed
```

Comment: How could I add this as a task inside my tasks, so that I can put all those tasks as prerequisites?

Comment: something like `task :bootstrap_my_app => ["db:drop", "db:create", "db:schema:load", "db:seed"]` should work.

Comment: `drop/create/load` can be replaced by `reset`

Answer (score 1):

You can also run `rake db:migrate:reset; rake db:seed`